# Why is the maximum number of nodes in a MongoDB Replica Set exactly 12?

Tags: mongodb, database-replication

Sorry for that dumb question, but why exactly that number? At first I thought it must only be **odd** number, but actually it is **7** as the maximum **voting node**, and overall a maximum of **12** nodes.  If you wish to run more than this, you must use the deprecated **master/slave** configuration.

So how to explain this number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All members of a replica set maintain knowledge of the current state of each of the other members.  This is the rationale for limiting the total number of nodes to twelve - more than that would introduce too much overhead in heartbeats between each pair of nodes.

Maximum of seven voting members is to avoid slowing down elections - since you need to have a consensus election to select a new primary limiting the number of nodes that need to coordinate amongst themselves will keep things faster.

Comment: but why the number 12 and 7, why not something like 13 or 11 and 8 and 6 ? is it from testing or this has a LAN bandwidth relation or relation with time latency?

Comment: I think if it was 13 you would ask "but why 13", right? :)  Some number had to be picked - large enough to hopefully be useful but not so large that performance would be impacted.

Comment: so this has not relation with something 'mathematically exact'?

Comment: @Abdelouahab, I think that it has always relation with something "mathematically exact", in fact Adam Comerford says they are working on it so it must have some explanation. If you've found something specific I'd like to know, thanks.

Comment: note that v3.0 has increased the number of total members to 50 - again the exact number is absolutely arbitrary, some limit had to be picked.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still wondering about this, the latest dev branch of MongoDB (2.7.8 as of writing this answer) has increased the overall limit to 50 as part of [SERVER-15060](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15060).  This change, assuming it is not reverted due to irreconcilable problems during testing, will be available in the 2.8 production release.  Note: the max number of voting nodes remains at 7 but this change should prevent the need to use the legacy master/slave configuration for those niche cases that require more than 12 nodes.